# How can I wait for an Activity to be finished to continue?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, certificate

As seen in this post : [How to wait for an activity to finish in asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579932/how-to-wait-for-an-activity-to-finish-in-asynctask)

I want to wait an Activity I launched from a Service to finish in order to return a value. Unfortunatly, this post have no answer :( I'll explain what I'm trying to expose a clear view of my issue :

I have this class :

```
public class CertificateConfigurationService {
    public boolean configureCertificate(Context context, CertificationConfiguration cert) {
             // ... code to create the certificate
             Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();
             intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_PKCS12, keystore);
             intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_NAME, cert.getName());
             intent.putExtra(KeyChain.EXTRA_CERTIFICATE, credential.getName());
             context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The issue is that I have a ConfigurationService which received JSON payload, that can contains multiple certificates to be pushed to the phone.

Here is the ConfigurationService part which is relevant to call configure :

```
... if(payload != null && payload.length() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < payload.length(); i++) {
                Configuration configuration;
                JSONObject currentObject = payload.getJSONObject(i);

                configuration = mapper.readValue(currentObject.toString(), Configuration.class);

                if (currentObject.getString("typeClass").equals("WLANConfiguration")) {
                    success = WifiConfigurationService.configureWifi(this.context, (WLANConfiguration) configuration);
                } else if (currentObject.getString("typeClass").equals("CertificateConfiguration")) {
                    success = CertificateConfigurationService.configureCertificate(this.context, (CertificateConfiguration) configuration);
                } ...
```

It works well with one certificate. 
But it comes to 2 certificates or more :

1. ConfigurationService loops through the two
2. Starts activity to type password for first certificate
   [image: Password prompt]
3. User have to type the password
4. Hence the second certificate is ignored, because user have not finished yet.

I'm not sharp enough with Android asynchronous tasks to see how I can wait for the user to have confirmed the password, to launch the second activity for the 2nd certificate. Plus, I'm not in an Activity when I do this.

Can you please draw me the big steps to follow if you already did something like this ? thanks !

**EDIT 1:**
I've seen that the phone log a debug when the certificate is installed :

> CertInstaller: credential is added

Is it simply possible to hook on this, and resume the configuration process after ?

**EDIT 2:**
I tried to store multiple certificates into one keystore, and then create an InstallIntent for this keystore, but still it seems it tries to extract only the first one.

Comment: You will have to set a clickListener on the OK Button and then start your method etc.

Comment: @MuratK. I can't really do this right ? As I'm starting a system activity `Intent intent = KeyChain.createInstallIntent();`, I don't have the control over the activity I start. or maybe creating an Activity extending the one provided by KeyChain.createInstallIntent ?

Comment: you probably want to use [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)... also mentioned in the [KeyChain#createInstallIntent Example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/KeyChain.html#createInstallIntent())

Comment: user0815 yes I saw this into the Android docs, but I can't use it outside of an Activity unfortunatly ...